# Correct configuration for omnicompletion with auto-complete

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I'm writing a minor-mode that uses custom auto-complete sources. I have a list of candidates (e.g. an object's methods) that I want to show immediately when <kbd>.</kbd> is pressed.

The [documentation](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#Omni_Completion) refers to this as 'omni-completion'. There is [some info](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete) on EmacsWiki, but `ac-omni-completion-sources` appears to be deprecated in the current version of auto-complete.

Is there a supported way to achieve this behaviour?